# SQL Updating table row on button click

Tags: php, html, sql

I am trying to update a specific row column in a table once a button is clicked. In my table, all rows have a "scheduled" column and its unique key is "orderid"

[image]

Now in my display table (using a for each), I added an if condition in the buttons (yes if 1 no if 0).

```
<td>
 <?php
    require_once($routePath . "_config/db.php");
    $dbConfig = new config_db();
    $db = $dbConfig->init();

    if (($rowOrder['sched']) == 1) {
    ?>
    button type="submit" id="sched_button" name="sched_button" value="SCHED_BUTTON" class="btn btn-success">YES</button>
    <?php
    } else if (($rowOrder['sched']) == 0) {
    ?>
    <button type="submit" id="sched_button" name="sched_button" value="SCHED_BUTTON" class="btn btn-danger">NO</button>
 <?php
    }
    ?> 
</td>
```

[image]

Here is my code for the button. I am trying to change 0 to 1 or 1 to 0. I know there is something missing with my SQL Update. What could I add so that the scheduled column is updated? (depending on the specific row where I clicked the button)

PS I had the "scheduled" column turn into a shortcut "sched"

```
  if (isset($_POST['sched_button']) && $_POST['sched_button'] == 'SCHED_BUTTON')
  {
    if (($rowOrder['sched']) == 1) {
      $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE order SET scheduled = 0'));
      $stmt->execute();
    } else if (($rowOrder['sched']) == 0) {
      $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE order SET scheduled = 1'));
      $stmt->execute();
    }

  }
```

Comment: @j you need to change the value attribute for both button Yes and No, so you can get it in post

Comment: you are updating the `packageid` column, but where is the column on the table?

Comment: @J you need to add where clause at update otherwise it will update to all rows

Comment: my bad, added scheduled in SET but nothing seems to be working

Comment: im just trying to get the button to function first before setting my where clause

Answer (score 1):

This is the quick method to update the `scheduled` column :

**the display**

```
<td>
<?php
    require_once($routePath . "_config/db.php");
    $dbConfig = new config_db();
    $db = $dbConfig->init();

    if (($rowOrder['sched']) == 1) {
    ?>
    <button type="submit" id="sched_button" name="sched_button" value="1" class="btn btn-success">YES</button>
    <?php
    } else if (($rowOrder['sched']) == 0) {
    ?>
    <button type="submit" id="sched_button" name="sched_button" value="0" class="btn btn-danger">NO</button>
<?php
    }
    ?> 
</td>
```

**the query**

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST['sched_button']))
{
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE order SET scheduled = ?"));
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $_POST['sched_button'];
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: SET should have been "scheduled" to be the same as column, my bad. Button is still not doing anything somehow.

Comment: Please do not use this code. This screams SQL Injection!!! Anyone could just modify the query here with a forged request and do what they want on the Database.

Comment: Hi @JensV, I've updated the code, it won't scream injection anymore ;)

Comment: Alright, the question is worded weirdly though. In my answer I assumed he meant how to update only the relevant order (as this will update every single row).

Answer (score 0):

Button `values` to 1 or 0 , then on on submit it’ll do the job

Edit; as @Hasta Dhana said you’re missing the column `packageid`

Comment: changed "packageid" to "scheduled" but the value is not changing

Comment: @JeremiahCanuto read the other comments you’re missing the where in your update

Answer (score 0):

```
     <button type="submit" id="sched_button" name="sched" value="<?php echo ($rowOrder['sched'] == 1 ? 0 : 1); ?>" class="btn btn-<?php echo ($rowOrder['sched'] == 1 ? "success" : "danger"); ?>"><?php echo ($rowOrder['sched'] == 1 ? "YES" : "NO"); ?></button>

if (isset($_POST['sched'])) {
                $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE order SET packageid =$_POST['sched']");
                $stmt->execute();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

display.php

```
<td>
    <?php
    require_once($routePath . "_config/db.php");
    $dbConfig = new config_db();
    $db = $dbConfig->init();

    if (($rowOrder['sched']) == 1) {
        ?>
        <button  class="btn btn-success" onclick="update(1,<?php echo $rowID; ?>)">YES</button>
        <?php
    } else if (($rowOrder['sched']) == 0) {
        ?>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="update(0,<?php echo $rowID; ?>)">NO</button>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</td>

<script>
    function update(value,id) {

        $.ajax({
            url: "update.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {"id": id, "value":value},
            success: function () {
                console.log('Updated');
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

update.php

```
<?php
require_once($routePath . "_config/db.php");
    $dbConfig = new config_db();
    $db = $dbConfig->init();

if(isset($_POST['id'])&& isset($_POST['value'])){

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $value = $_POST['value'];

    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE order SET scheduled = $value WHERE orderid = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);  // Bind "$id" to parameter. 
    $stmt->execute();

}
```

Comment: not sure how that variable $rowID works in your answer, its not anywhere in my code

Comment: You need to make it if you want to update only 1 row in table, not whole table. $rowID can be orderid from your database

Answer (score 0):

So your issue is, the form handler has no idea which orderid to process. You could adapt your form to something like this:

```
<td>
    <?php
    require_once($routePath . "_config/db.php");
    $dbConfig = new config_db();
    $db = $dbConfig->init();
    ?>
    <button type="submit" id="sched_button" name="sched_button_<?= $rowOrder['sched'] ?>" value="<?= $rowOrder['orderid'] ?>" class="btn btn-success">YES</button>
</td>
```

This will either submit with `sched_button_0` or `sched_button_1` and the value is the orderid.

Your handler could look something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['sched_button_0'])) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE order SET scheduled = 1 WHERE orderid = ?');
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST['sched_button_0']);
    $stmt->execute();
} else if (isset($_POST['sched_button_1'])) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE order SET scheduled = 0 WHERE orderid = ?');
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST['sched_button_0']);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

I am assuming you're using mysqli to connect to the database.